# mpmathのextraprecについて

Tags: python, python3

python3でプログラムを作っています。
その過程でmpmathの中のpolyrootsを使っています。
そのコードで`extraprec`という一文があるのですがこの一文は何をするためのコードか教えて下さい。

```
mpmath.polyroots([a,b,c,d,e,f],maxsteps=3000,cleanup=True, extraprec=400,error=True
```

Answer (score 0):

与えられた多項式のすべての根を計算する際の、**計算精度を拡張するためのパラメータ**でしょう。

以下の記事の回答が関連しそうです。(デフォルト値に整合性の無い記述がありますが)
訳はgoogleを使っているので正確ではないかもしれません。(コメント指摘のtypo修正済)
[Finding the roots of a simple polynomial with mpmath](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31543071/9014308)

> The documentation mentions that increasing extraprec may be necessary to achieve convergence. This is the case for your example, due to root multiplicity.
>
> ```
> >>> mpmath.polyroots(p, maxsteps=100, extraprec=110)
> [mpf('0.0'), mpf('4.0'), mpf('4.0'), mpf('4.0')]
> ```
>
> The extraprec parameter means the extra number of digits to be used in the process of calculation, compared the number of digits needed in the result (which is 15 by default, set globally in mpmath.mp.dps). Its default value is 10; increasing it to 110 achieves convergence in 100 steps. This actually takes less time than trying (and failing) to find the roots with maxsteps=2000 at the default extraprec level.

訳：
ドキュメンテーションは、収束を達成するためには、extraprecを増やすことが必要かもしれないと述べています。これは根の多重度による、あなたの例の場合です。

**extraprecパラメータは、計算および比較の過程で使用される追加の桁数、結果に必要な桁数の拡張を意味します。**(デフォルトは15です。mpmath.mp.dpsでグローバルに設定されています)
デフォルト値は10です。110に増やすと、100ステップで収束します。
これは実際にはmaxsteps = 2000でデフォルトのextraprecレベルで根を見つけることを試みる（そして失敗する）よりも短い時間で済みます。

---

**mpmathのドキュメントに以下のように記述されています**
同じく訳はgoogleを使っているので正確ではないかもしれません。

[Polynomial roots (polyroots)](http://mpmath.org/doc/1.1.0/calculus/polynomials.html#polynomial-roots-polyroots)

> ```
> mpmath.polyroots(coeffs, maxsteps=50, cleanup=True, extraprec=10, error=False, roots_init=None)
> ```
>
> Computes all roots (real or complex) of a given polynomial.
>
> The roots are returned as a sorted list, where real roots appear first followed by complex conjugate roots as adjacent elements. The polynomial should be given as a list of coefficients, in the format used by polyval(). The leading coefficient must be nonzero.
>
> With error=True, polyroots() returns a tuple (roots, err) where err is an estimate of the maximum error among the computed roots.

訳：
与えられた多項式のすべての根（実数または複素数）を計算します。

根はソートされたリストとして返されます。実際の根が最初で、その後に隣接要素として複素共役根があらわれます。多項式は、polyval()で使用されるフォーマットで、係数のリストとして与えられるべきです。先行係数はゼロ以外でなければなりません。

error=Trueの場合、polyroots()はタプル(roots, err)を返します。ここで、errは計算された根の中の最大誤差の推定値です。

> Precision and conditioning
>
> The roots are computed to the current working precision accuracy. If this accuracy cannot be achieved in maxsteps steps, then a NoConvergence exception is raised. The algorithm internally is using the current working precision extended by extraprec. If NoConvergence was raised, that is caused either by not having enough extra precision to achieve convergence (in which case increasing extraprec should fix the problem) or too low maxsteps (in which case increasing maxsteps should fix the problem), or a combination of both.
>
> The user should always do a convergence study with regards to extraprec to ensure accurate results. It is possible to get convergence to a wrong answer with too low extraprec.
>
> Provided there are no repeated roots, polyroots() can typically compute all roots of an arbitrary polynomial to high precision:

訳：
精度と条件付け

根は現在の作業精度で計算されます。この精度がmaxstepsステップで達成できない場合は、NoConvergence例外が発生します。アルゴリズムは内部的にextraprecによって拡張された現在の作業精度を使用しています。NoConvergenceが発生した場合は、収束を達成するのに十分な余計な精度がない（この場合、extraprecを増やすと問題が解決する）か、小さすぎるmaxsteps（この場合、maxstepsを増やすと問題が解決する）、または両方の組み合わせが原因です。

ユーザーは正確な結果を確実にするために常にextraprecを考慮して収束の調査(研究?)をするべきです。低すぎるextraprecは間違った答えに収束する可能性があります。

繰り返し根がない場合、polyroots()は通常、任意の多項式のすべての根を高精度に計算できます。